# Link to create new node with taxonomy term from url already selected?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I need to make a link to create a new node. I need this link to appear on taxonomy term pages so I was going to put it in a block. Nodes can be tagged with taxonomy terms.

How can I make it so the create node form has the term (from the page the link was on) already selected? So if you were on mysite.com/term/1 and and clicked the create node link, the node would have term 1 already selected.

Ive found this module but its in dev for D7 so there another way?
http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the Prepopulate module is in fact safe. It has a large number of sites using it and was mentioned in a mustardseed media screencast. 
http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate

Comment: Have you found documentation telling you how you do this [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate)? The syntax for taxonomy on the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/228167) (`http://www.example.com/node/add/content?edit[taxonomy][1]=2`) does not to work. The syntax in the file `USAGE.txt` (`http://www.example.com/node/add/content?edit[taxonomy][tags][1]=test`) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to download and enable the [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

The syntax you use to prepopulate taxonomy terms with D7 is (AFAIK) not documented anywhere and the syntax it is also radically different from the syntax used in D6 that is demoed in a number of screencasts of the Preopulate module.  In D7 taxonomy terms are fields.  If you read the source code, you'll find that you prepopulate taxonomy terms as would prepopulate other field.

I.e. if your taxonomy term field is `field_tags` and you want to prepopulate with the term "myterm", you use the following syntax (with clean URLs):
`/node/add/article?edit[field_tags][und]=myterm`.